# Can elementary particles be rightfully considered quasiparticles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

Can elementary particles rightfully considered quasiparticles? I have this association, because renormalization makes particle properties, like mass and couplings, energy-dependent quantities, even in vacuum. I see this as a result of the interactions between the moving particle with virtual particles forming the quantum-vacuum from which they get self-energy contributions. In that sense any real particle appears as an emergent quantum. Of course, their symmetry-properties (like spin) will remain those of the bare fields of the theory (in contrast to condensed matter quasiparticles whose properties may differ from those of their constituents). I wonder if there is something in the quasiparticle concept which forbids this association.

Comment: Robert Laughlin (Nobel laureate for the fractional quantum Hall effect) wrote a fascinating book called *A Different Universe* which touches on this topic; his answer is "yes, they can."

Comment: What is the definition of "quasiparticle" here?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Probably there is no exact definition (at least I don't know one). I would invent: A localized (in the limits of quantum mechanics) excitation which allows for a simplified effective particle description of properties of many-body systems.

Comment: A quasi-particle is the same thing as a particle: it's a bunch of measured quantum numbers (except that the quasi-particle is the APPROXIMATE interaction of two or more APPROXIMATELY separable states of the system). Neither have a physical existence of their own outside of your imagination. I think the hard part is to let go of the idea that this universe is somehow made of little balls. It's not. It's made of ONE very complex quantum field that only yields quantized measurements.

Comment: @CuriousOne I think that mass and width are as well to be considered properties of an elementary particle. As I pointed out, their values can only be approximate in a renormalized theory (they become momentum dependent). I am not sure if size matters. In a kinetic description in particle approximation the size will be set to zero in any case. I do not insinuate that elementary particles are composite, even though technically quantum-loops can contribute in their propagation.

Comment: The size of the number that my printer prints out after I do a quantum measurement has no meaning for the experiment. Neither has the mass of the paper and the ink it is printed on. Seriously, you have to let go of the idea that you are dealing with balls of some sort. It's a distraction and distortion of what we are really dealing with when we are looking at quantum fields.

Comment: @CuriousOne I tried to explain that I am not thinking of balls of some sort.

Comment: Well, you were talking about "particle properties" in your question, which usually indicates that there is something like that in play. Do you understand why we have "particles" in accelerator experiments and why they do not matter for the interpretation of the theory?

Comment: In S-matrix formalism (which I think is limited for unstable particles) particle=state and the states have a specific (on-shell) four momentum from it I may compute mass (and width). Is this what you mean?